# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Ok in this situation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am following certain sections of [this tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) but I am wondering if this using "*" is safe to do or if I should be putting it as my domain name?

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your specific use case.

Ideally you should limit this to as few as possible - your own domain if you can (or a list of domains if it will be more than one) - but if you need to allow public access to that API then you will have to allow "*".

I should also point out that you can set your CORS restrictions on a very granular basis - e.g. for each method, if you need to. See example below from MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
  return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Comment: In another part of the tutorial they use    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);. Do they work with each other or override each other?

Comment: They can be used together - as in you can define a global policy, and then override the global setting by decorating specific classes/methods which have different requirements.

Comment: So if I would change this to:   context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "MyDomain" }); then it would cancel out pp.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);.correct?

Comment: Yes, local Cors settings override global settings. See this official MS article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors